# Yii - How can I submit a form and send a user to a given anchor?

Tags: php, yii

I need to achieve in Yii something like this:

```
<form action="somescript.php#fragment-id">
```

Once the form get's submitted, the success message should appear in front of the user eyes. 
At this time, the message is displaying BUT, the browser goes back to the top.

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id'=>'contact-form',
                    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                )); ?>

  //form here
  <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('send')); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

I see something here called `actionPrefix`, but it seems to be coming from another class:

```
CWidget
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm

I've tried to add `actionPrefix` like so:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id'=>'contact-form',
                    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                    'actionPrefix'=>'fragment-id'
                )); ?>
```

No dice.

Please advice

Comment: Is the form being submitted by ajax (page not reloading after submitting)

Comment: no. the page is reloading. no ajax here.

Comment: yes. it is the same page reloading.

Comment: in your action that receives the form submit, have you tried redirecting to the relevant URL eg: $this->redirect("yourpage#fragment-id");

Comment: no I'm not. by "yourpage" do you mean the rendered view ? (in this case it would be index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller/action that receives your form submit, once the form is processed, simply redirect to the URL you want. eg:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/myurl#fragment-id");
```

You can even get real fancy and use this short jQuery scroll to function:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

Which get's called like so:

```
goToByScroll("theIdIWantToGoTo");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `action` attribute of `CActiveForm`. repalce `'controller/acion'` with your specific needs.

```
  <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                        'id'=>'contact-form',
                        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                        'action'=>array('controller/acion','#'=>'fragment-id')
                    )); ?>
```

Comment: This is indeed a nice way for doing it. I will however place that code into the controller with direct - I tend to have my views a little but full already. But truly is a nice way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the wrong option. what you need its [action](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail):

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id'=>'contact-form',
                    'action'=>$this->createUrl('')."#fragment-id",
                    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                )); ?>

  //form here
  <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('send')); ?>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

The empty params for the `createUrl` its to generate an URL for the ccurrently requested URL